# Bootstrap 4: Is there default css class for vertical-align-middle for p tag?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

There is default css class for text-center for p tag.
Is there default css class for vertical-align-middle for p tag?
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 border">
            <p class="text-center">Need text-center and align-middle</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:
[image: Output]

What is I need:
[image: What is I need]

Comment: `p` tag has default `margin-bottom`. Just remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to `p` tag have by default `margin-bottom:16px`.

Hope this may help you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 border p-2">
            <p class="text-center mb-0">Need text-center and align-middle</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I always use this website http://howtocenterincss.com/ to see how to center css and it always do wonders for me

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    Text Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of p tag have default margin you have to set it 0;

```
p{
margin: 0;
}
```